# How to fix point meta self-interference?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading

The following diagram is what I want the sphere to look like:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{90}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, axis lines=center, ticks=none, view/h=120, view/v=20, enlarge x limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge y limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge z limits={abs=2pt}]
% axis line style={latex-latex}
    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.65, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({-x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{-x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{-x});
%sphere
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, point meta={x + 2*y + 3*z}, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(0,0,0)rgb255=(250,250,250)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 50,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:180, y domain = 0:360] ({2*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {2*cos(v)});
%viviani window underlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%equator cylinder
    \addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=30, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1-cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
%hidden axes
    \addplot3+[domain=-2:2, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, densely dotted, black]({x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=-2:2, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, densely dotted, black]({0},{x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=-2:2, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, densely dotted, black]({0},{0},{x});
%viviani cylinder parts
%    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, point meta={4*x + 8*y - 2}, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(255,255,255)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
%    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = -180:180, y domain = -2:0, ] ({1-cos(u)}, {-sin(u)}, {min(-sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
%    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, point meta={4*x + 8*y - 2}, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(255,255,255)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
%    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = -180:180, y domain = 0:2, ] ({1-cos(u)}, {-sin(u)}, {max(sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
%viviani window overlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=-pi/3:2*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=5*pi/3:8*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=2.34375:4.5325, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%axis extensions
    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.625, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{x});
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But when I uncomment the cylinder parts, this happens instead:

[image]

I am not sure what is happening here and I would like it to stop.

The only observation I can make is that I have used point meta more than once, and when I change the point meta for either plot, it changes the shading on both plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the variation of the sphere is smaller than the one of the cylinder. Why does that matter? In the survey phase `pgfplots` checks what the minima and maxima are of all plots, and then comes up with a formula such that the maximal point meta corresponds to the upper end of the color spectrum and the minimal point meta to the lower end. So all you need to do is to modify the point meta of the sphere by multiplying it by some number (and by a constant).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{90}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, axis lines=center, ticks=none, view/h=120, view/v=20, enlarge x limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge y limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge z limits={abs=2pt}]
% axis line style={latex-latex}
    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.65, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({-x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{-x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{-x});
%sphere
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, point meta={(x + 2*y + 3*z)*4-2}, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(0,0,0)rgb255=(250,250,250)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 50,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:180, y domain = 0:360] ({2*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {2*cos(v)});
%viviani window underlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%equator cylinder
    \addplot3+[domain=0:2*pi, samples=30, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1-cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
%hidden axes
    \addplot3+[domain=-2:2, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, densely dotted, black]({x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=-2:2, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, densely dotted, black]({0},{x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=-2:2, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, densely dotted, black]({0},{0},{x});
%viviani cylinder parts
   \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, point meta={4*x + 8*y - 2}, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(255,255,255)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
   variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = -180:180, y domain = -2:0, ] ({1-cos(u)}, {-sin(u)}, {min(-sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
   \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, point meta={4*x + 8*y - 2}, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(50,50,50)rgb255=(255,255,255)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
   variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = -180:180, y domain = 0:2, ] ({1-cos(u)}, {-sin(u)}, {max(sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
%viviani window overlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=-pi/3:2*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=5*pi/3:8*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=2.34375:4.5325, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%axis extensions
    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.625, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.5pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{x});
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]